# useContext(Context) show warning on console in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I have use `React Context API` hook in react native. I created `Consumer` and `Provider` both to pass props and state from parent to child. Code is working perfectly fine, I have received props from parent to child.

**I have received following warning on my console:-**

> Warning: Calling useContext(Context.Consumer) is not supported, may
>   cause bugs, and will be removed in a future major release. Did you
>   mean to call useContext(Context) instead?

**Please check below added code:-**

I have create common context file `CommonContext.js`.

```
import React, {createContext} from 'react';

const MyContext = createContext();
export const LoginProvider = MyContext.Provider;
export const LoginConsumer = MyContext.Consumer;
```

This is my provider code

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {LoginProvider} from './CommonContext';

export default class Login extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={Styles.mainContainer}>       
        <LoginProvider value={this.props}>
          <LoginScreenView />
        </LoginProvider>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

From this way i am access parent component data into child hook

```
import {LoginConsumer} from './CommonContext';
export default function LoginScreenView(props) {
  let loginConsumer = useContext(LoginConsumer);
return (
    <View style={Styles.mainContainer}>
      <Text>{loginConsumer}</Text>
    </View>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are receiving this error because you are calling `useContext` on a `Context.Consumer` instance, instead of a `Context`.

You do like this:

```js
export const LoginConsumer = MyContext.Consumer;
```

and then you call `useContext` on `LoginConsumer`:

```js
let loginConsumer = useContext(LoginConsumer);
```

Instead, you should call `useContext` on `MyContext`, like this:

1. Export the context from `CommonContext.js`:

```js
export const MyContext = createContext();
```

2. Import the context instead of the context consumer in the file where you're using it:

```js
import { MyContext } from './CommonContext';
```

3. and then using it with `useContext`:

```js
let login = useContext(MyContext);
```

So your second component that you posted would look like this:

```js
import { MyContext } from './CommonContext';

export default function LoginScreenView(props) {
  let login = useContext(MyContext);
  return (
    <View style={Styles.mainContainer}>
      <Text>{login}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: where is provider and consumer and how we will pass data from parent to child??

Comment: @VishalDhanotiya `login` is the data from the context. The value in `<LoginProvider value={this.props}>` is the value returned from `useContext(MyContext)`

Comment: @VishalDhanotiya It shouldn't do that if you're calling useContext on the context itself and not it's consumer